# Finding the cryptographic hashing algorithm, given the plain text and the corresponding salted hash

Tags: hash, salt, cryptanalysis

I have a salted hash (say about, 110 characters long) and the corresponding plain text that I used for hashing. As the title says, is it possible to do find the algorithm via crypt-analysis? What is the recommended approach, if it exists?

Comment: You can bruteforce

Comment: Can you give some background? Is this a practical problem that you have?

Comment: There's really not enough information to answer the question.  Can you give an example hash and plaintext?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Yes. If by *cryptographic hashing algorithm* you mean (an unkeyed version of) one of the [well known ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cryptographic_hash_functions), then you can simply try all of them. There's not too many of them.

No. If by *cryptographic hashing algorithm* you mean just *any* such algo, then no. There are infinitely many of these.
(And you can trivially generate new hashing algorithms, simply by turning one of the unkeyed hashes into a keyed variant by plugging that hash and a random key into [the HMAC construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) for example. They will then behave like a completely new hashing algorithm.)